# In jquery, is there a way to iterate over a jQuery array without $(this)?

Tags: jquery

I know the standard way of doing it:

```
$('div').each(function(){
      // here `this` is bound to DOM Element
      // use $(this) to access the jQuery wrapper
})'
```

But this is a little bit cumbersome because we need to use `$(this)` everywhere and this causes a performance penalty as shown by http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-this.

I am looking for a way to iterate over a jQuery array/selector with `this` bound to the jQuery wrapper instead of to the DOM element.

Comment: well if you don't need jQuery methods you can just use 'this', but if you need jQuery methods you can only cache '$(this)' to a variable and use that variable.

Comment: Just don't use it. Because I think that's the jQuery overhead you get when you use it.

Comment: According to your test, the expression `$(this)` is evaluated in 2 microseconds on my machine (and I have a really slow laptop). Now, a microsecond is a millionth of a second, so you don't have to worry about performance here.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Consider a table-like structure with over 1000 records. What do you think about it?

Comment: @RobW That would still be just a few milliseconds on my machine, and less than a millisecond on most desktops. That's certainly not an performance issue. If you have really many records on the page (like 100,000), you probably don't want to use jQuery for processing anyway, but instead want to write your own highly-optimized code.

Comment: I don't think you'll find a satisfying answer to your question. If you need the jQuery wrapper, well, jQuery has to build it for you, this is the goal of $(this). jQuery doesn't have a wrapper for each DOM element ready "for free".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an ordinary loop. and use `.slice(index, 1)` to get the corresponding jQuery object.

[`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) does the same thing, and maps to [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/), so `.slice(i, 1)` is more efficient than `.eq(index)`.

```
var $divs = $('div');
for (var i=0; i <$divs.length; i++) {
    $divs.slice(i);
}
```

Notice that the closure is not present. If you want to use closures, create a temporary function:

```
function eachMethod(index, $elem) { /* ... */ }
var $divs = $('div');
for (var i=0; i <$divs.length; i++) {
    eachMethod(i, $divs.slice(i, 1));
    // Or, if you even want to preserve `this`
    // eachMethod.call($divs[i], i, $divs.slice(i, 1));
}
```

### Update: A [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) to achieve your desired "each-syntax":

```
(function($) {
    $.fn._each = function(method) {
        // this points to the jQuery collection
        for (var i=0; i <this.length; i++) {
            method.call(this[i], i, this.slice(i, 1));
        }
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
// Usage:
$('div')._each(function(index, $elem) {
    // this points to the DOM element
    // index to the index
    // $elem to the jQuery-wrapped DOM element
});
```

Comment: The problem here is that we have loosed the `.each()` syntax.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit See my updated answer. Enjoy your "each-syntax".

Comment: Why the  first parameter to `method.call` is `this[i]` and not `this.slice(i,1)`?

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit `method.call(thisObject, arg1, arg2)` invokes the `method(arg1, arg2)`, setting `this` to `thisObject`. See [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is a native JavaScript method.

Comment: I know. But I think that `this` should also be set to the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit Why? You've already got `$elem` to refer to the jQuery object. If you also want `this` to be a jQuery wrapper, replace `method.call(...)` with `var $this=this.slice(i,1);method.call($this, i, $this);`.

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit if you're going to use each(), then you are creating a scope for each iteration; the whole topic of performance is moot.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the [.toArray()](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/)  that jQuery offers?

```
var divs = $('div').toArray();

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    // do something with divs[i]
  }
```

Would that be faster?

Comment: `toArray()` returns a DOM Element array. I want to iterate over the jQuery wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this...

```
$k = $(this)  // the $ in $k is not really necessary but helps readability
```

and then use it wherever you want without any processing

```
$k.hide()
```

Comment: executing `$k = $(this)` causes a performance penalty so I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = $('div');
for( var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ ) {
    elements.eq(i);
}
```

Comment: touché! I know it says yours was 43 seconds ago, but the bar appeared right when I posted ;)  Also, if I might presume to suggest? Since we're talking about performance, elements.length has some overhead in IE and scoping it local (`var len = elements.length`) [is 50% faster to iterate](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html) a large number of items

Answer (score 0):

```
var $this, $elements = $(selector), len = $elements.length;
for(var i=0; i < len; i++) {
   $this = $elements.eq(i);
}
```

Since you've mentioned performance, and I'll just trust you have a bottleneck and you aren't obsessing over code without and actual problem, there are some other things you can do as well.

Scope variables locally whenever possible. (note len = $elements.length above).

If the order of the iteration doesn't matter, you can speed things up even more:

```
var $this, $elements = $(selector), i = $elements.length;
while(i--) {
   $this = $elements.eq(i);
}
```

Comment: `.eq(0)`? Think you meant `.eq(i)`

Comment: ha! I was trying to outtype you!